# how to enable links in the footer

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an HTML snippet as follows

```css
.footer {
    padding: 20px 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    background : $footerBGColor;
}
   
.footer:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.1;
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438368915865-a852ef86fc42?q=80&fm=jpg&s=15e4744077e36852ba57f46f4660dc7a');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
       
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 md-margin-bottom-40">
                <h2>About</h2>
                <p class="margin-bottom-25 md-margin-bottom-40">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, necessitatibus!
                    <span><a href="#" class="small"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a></span>
                </p>    

               
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 footerImage">

                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <address class="md-margin-bottom-40">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled address">
                        <li>Lorem</span></li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </address>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="copyright">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row col-md-11">
            <p class="text-center">
                <small><?php echo(date('Y')) ?> &copy; All Rights Reserved. 
                <small><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="#">Terms of Service</a></small></small>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I am planning to make footer.svg display as the background of the footer. I have noticed that if I remove the content style from the footer:before, my links in the footer work, but the background image does not render. However if I enable the content style, my links don't work, but the background image is not being rendered.

Can you please help me out with this?

When you run the snippet , note that the links do not work. If you remove the content , the snippet works.

Thanks

With Regards
Gagan

Comment: The sentence under your code doesn't make sense. "If it do this it works, but if I do that it works". Do you have a can/can't or start/stop typo perhaps?  Also it would help if you create a working code snippet or fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image overlays everything. Change the ".footer:before"  z-index to "-1".

Comment: sure that will work, but in that case, the background image does not render.

Comment: Not sure how you got it working on Chrome , but I am on chrome and it does not render for me.. https://infinit.io/_/VBPbiaX

Comment: Now it works in IE, the Image took so long to load in my IE. 

What's inside your $footerBGColor ? comment it out, just for a try. because, if i change that color to whatever i want it overpaints the backgroundimage. 

That's why it works for Gerardo Ramirez and me - we don't have that variable.

Comment: I changed it to red .. and its still not working.. https://infinit.io/_/3etri5f .. $footerBGColor was a sass variable.

Comment: Just remove that variable - give it a try.
Or add an alpha-value:    background-color:  rgba(255,0,0,0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
z-index: 1 to -1
```

https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/vcfee42L/

Comment: Not sure how you got it working on Chrome , but I am on chrome and it does not render for me.. https://infinit.io/_/VBPbiaX